# Fragment Tag vs pragmatically adding a Fragment to your layout

Tags: android, static, calendar

**Final Update**

Turns out that I had the problem all wrong. It was how I was using the Fragment tag. See my answer below to get a full explanation.

**Update 3**:
So I have continued messing with it for hours with no such luck. I have been able to get it to a point in which it does not crash. But now I believe I know what the issue might be. It was getting my `calendarAdapter` as null because it was null, but not by my intention. It seems `onCreateView` is running twice, once apparently before anything is sent in and after I have officially sent some parameters. This of course should not be happening... I think. I will provide the part in which my ActionBar is set at the bottom so you can let me know if I am doing something wrong for this behavior to be set the way it is.

---

I am having an issue with this specific thing for some reason, and I have no idea why. I have an Activity called `MainDisplayActivity` as well as a Fragment called `MainDislpayFragment`. As you can imagine, the Activity sets the Fragment on app start. Now this is the problem, I've been trying to sent as parameters into the `newInstance` constructor three numbers that came from a Calendar. Then I created the Calendar from within the constructor. But my app crashes. The weird part is when I keep the Calendar from being used by static fields the app works as expected, but trying to use the Calendar from anything that came from the constructor makes it crash. This is an example method:

```
private static Calendar cal;

static MainDisplayFragment newInstance(Context context, int y, int m, int d) {

    c = context;
    MainDisplayFragment f = new MainDisplayFragment();
    //static global Calendar now
            cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(y, m, d);
}//end of static newInstance method
```

Now its important to note that even if I tried taking Calendar out and putting it in onCreate and only having the static ints I am getting back as global, and setting them there, it still causes a crash. The notable error and the weird thing is that it seems to think Calendar is null for some reason. As you can tell right there it is definitely being created. But now I am starting to think there is an issue with Calendar and static fields. If it does not, then I may have an error, but I wanted to rule that out if I can. Thanks for anyones response.

**Update:** I should mention that I am using that Calendar info for nothing more than to pass into my `MyCalendarAdapter`. Regardless of whether I only send in numbers as a parameter or a Calendar itself, it crashes. The first null exception I see is where I am trying to set the `MyCalendarAdapter`.

Line 75 would be the last lin here:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    calendarAdapter = new MyCalendarAdapter(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

**UPDATE 2**:

---

After more messing around I realized the issue is with `MyCalendarAdapter`, but its an issue that makes no sense. It seems if you instantiate a calendarAdapter with no arguments it works perfectly, but with arguments it crashes. These are the two constructors for `MyCalendarAdapter` so people can see that nothing looks wrong, which makes this worse because I have no friggen idea how to fix this. Its also important to know that this code that I have tried to move to a Fragment originally came from an Activity, which worked perfectly.

```
public MyCalendarAdapter() {
    thisMonth = Calendar.getInstance();
    now = new MonthDisplayHelper(thisMonth.get(Calendar.YEAR), thisMonth.get(Calendar.MONTH));//creating Helper for month display
    currentDay = thisMonth.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);//sets current day

    ...

}

public MyCalendarAdapter(int year, int month, int currentDay) {
    thisMonth = Calendar.getInstance();
    now = new MonthDisplayHelper(year, month);
    this.currentDay = currentDay;

    ...

}
```

**Complete List of Errors**:

---

```
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start 
activity ComponentInfo{com.zeroe/com.zeroe.MainDisplayActivity}:   
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at    
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
com.zeroe.MainDisplayActivity.onCreate(MainDisplayActivity.java:60)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     ... 11 more
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
com.zeroe.MainDisplayFragment.onCreateView(MainDisplayFragment.java:80)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:807)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1013)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1112)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4664)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
11-08 18:26:35.710: E/AndroidRuntime(7839):     ... 21 more
```

**ActionBar part where Fragment is set**

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Position is "+itemPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(itemPosition == 0) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        //check to see if one already exists and remove it
        Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MAIN_FRAGMENT);
        if(prev!=null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fragment was found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        MyCalendarAdapter calendarAdapter = new MyCalendarAdapter(year, month, day);
        //Log.d("MAINDISPLAYACTIVTY", "calendarAdapter year is "+calendarAdapter.getCalendar().getYear());
        currentFragment = MainDisplayFragment.newInstance(this, year, month, day, calendarAdapter);
        ft.add((MainDisplayFragment)currentFragment, MAIN_FRAGMENT);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        //ft.addToBackStack(null); //i do not want this behavior
        ft.commit();
        return true;
    }
... continues on with the other cases
```

**onCreate in Activity that sets the ActionBar**

```
final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(new ArrayAdapter<String>(bar.getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                                                    new String[]{"MONTH", "WEEK", "DAY"}), this);

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
    } else {
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_NAVIGATION_STATE));
    }
```

Comment: No problem instantiating Calendar there. Can you show us the Calendar static field declaration, how you access it and the stack trace of the NPE?

Comment: @m0skit0 added some more information. At least the relavant kind

Comment: What is currentDate and where is it set? this is not visible in above code samples

Comment: Oops, sorry. Typo. Was messing around with it some more. On here I decided to call it `cal`, but its actually `currentDate` in my code

Comment: Which line is MainDisplayFragment.java:75? Anyway you have to first fix your XML at the first error.

Comment: The last line is the very last line of the question. I am pretty sure I mention that above. But the xml is right. I am sure of it. I honestly think it has to do with static fields. But I am not sure because I never had this problem.

Comment: I added an update 2 @m0skit0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what my issue was. It was something that was not too clear in the Android docs on Fragments. I was using the `<fragment/>` tag in my main.xml file. I was using it correctly, and when creating my Fragment, I was also setting it correctly. Unfortunately I was not getting the behavior I was hoping for.

It turns out that if you use the fragment tag in your xml then when `setContentView` runs it will also run your Fragment class immediately (at least when it encounters the tag as its going down the file). What this means is if your Fragment depends on information from the Activity you are launching it from, it will not have it, and essentially run twice; when setContentView runs, and when you actually run your Fragment pragmatically. This is important because I was under the assumption that you could choose either way to run your Fragment. But in reality the way you design your app or approach it actually dictates which way you should go, hardcode a Fragment or pragmatically on the fly.

Maybe this was obvious to the android experts, but I am new to Fragments, so I guess it was a rookie mistake. In either case, this should really be detailed in the Android docs. Hope this helps anyone else completely confused on the issue.